# Get url path from Angular 2 router observer

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a (new) Router observable in my angular project that I use to check if a user is alowed to visit pages. It currently looks as follows:

```
    this._router.changes.subscribe(
        validate => {
            if (// !Check if user has access rights) {
                this._router.navigate(['/login']);
            }
        }
    )
```

The problem is that this results in an infinite loop, because my navigate call triggers the observer again. What would be the best way to solve this?

I would expect the best way is to somehow retrieve the location of the "change" that is being made, but I do not know how to retrieve it.

Comment: This is about the new router in `rc.1`?

Comment: I guess `CanActivate` lifecycle callback would be what you need but that's not yet implemented for the new router.